# creating windows app that runs on .NET 3.5 or 4

Tags: .net, windows

According to [.NET docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by specifying both CLR runtimes in the config file, I can tell my app to use either .NET 4 or .NET 3.5, I need to achieve this b/c Windows 7 has .NET 3.5 bulitin where as Windows 8 has .NET 4.

Specifically my config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup></configuration>
```

My app compiles fine on .NET 3.5 and .NET 4, but I use 3.5 in production. When I run my app on Windows 8, it asks me to install .NET 3.5. Shouldn't the config file have 
have taken care of this? Is the doc wrong or is there something I'm missing?

I'm using Visual Studios 2010 to compile my app.

Comment: I would advise to go with .net 4.0. Windows 7 DOES have an auto-update (after SP1) which contains the 4.0 framework, so unless you want your app to run on a fresh vanilla install of windows 7 without modifications, it's not worth being constrained to 3.5.

Comment: thanks @Vlad, that solved my requirements